# PytestUnknownMarkWarning изменяющийся маркер

Tags: python, pytest, allure

Использование такой строки

```
@allure.link(url="FS-Y813", name="Ссылка на кейс FS-Y813.")
```

приводит к предупреждению:

---

```
C:\Users\iam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\mark\structures.py:327
  C:\Users\iam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\mark\structures.py:327: PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.allure_link.link:FS-Y813 - is this a typo?  You can register custom marks to avoid this warning - for details, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/mark.html
    PytestUnknownMarkWarning,
```

---

То есть у нас не определен маркер "allure_link.link:FS-Y815". Я могу добавить этот маркер в pytest.ini, но проблема в том что для каждого теста формируется разный маркер (не спрашивайте почему так сделано :)). А вроде как маркер маской не задать.

Используется pytest версии 4.6.3 и обновлять нельзя.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ игнорировать данную ошибку, а лучше вовсе решить ее. Ибо она лишь создает много ненужных сообщений и никакой пользы.

---

**Решение**: добавить в pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::pytest.PytestUnknownMarkWarning
    ignore::urllib3.connectionpool.InsecureRequestWarning
```

---

```
ignore::urllib3.connectionpool.InsecureRequestWarning
```

тоже оказалось полезным, чтоб убрать ошибку

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
            InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Comment: Если нашли решение - добавьте ответом, а не в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение, добавить в pytest.ini:

```html
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::pytest.PytestUnknownMarkWarning
```